# Per-site blog publicity

Tags: discussion, blog-overflow, publicity

How are sites drumming up publicity for their site blogs?

Some of our users, I suspect, don't even know the site has a blog. We could use system messages when we put up a new post, but that's clunky - you can't schedule those in advance - and, if there's a new system message every week for something non-critical, then the system message will lose it's urgency. And the messages are meat for more urgent events in any case.

What strategies for promotion of site blogs are working well?

Comment: Great discussion to talk about *how* to promote per-site blogs, but **just a side note:** A system message that displays on every single page on the site (and is completely *non-dismissable*) isn't really an appropriate use of that feature.

Comment: @Robert - Yep, I was mostly mentioning it here to head off people from suggesting it.

Answer (score 7):

The "chat" link is substituted for the "(new) blog" link whenever there is a new post.  This is shown for 24 hours.

And, with "(new)" being in claret red, it's kinda hard to miss!

[image]

This is just one element of publicity, I'm unsure of what else is underway.

Comment: You mean the chat link at the top? Im not familiar with Claret red, but if its similar at all to the red used at the header bar already, people might miss it.

Comment: @Chris: Blood red - it's pretty bright and outstanding.

Comment: Still red probably isn't a good color to choose from. If I came to SO and saw red, im going to quickly glance down at the questions link and not notice it. Now on the other hand if it flashed red, blue, floresent green, and black, then I might notice it.

Comment: Is this for the per-site blog or the main SE blog or both?

Comment: @NeilFein both.

Comment: Nevertheless, people are obviously not seeing this (or not understanding what they're seeing).

Comment: ...but it is a step in the direction of helping the problem.

Comment: This is not working *at all*. Either that, or our blog is just incredibly boring. The only way people are submitting posts is if I bug them to do it, and that's not viable at all. And viewers? Forget it, almost nobody's reading the blog.

Comment: @NeilFein: One point might be (and I'm waiting to see the _(new)_ again to test this theory) that when clicking on _(new)_ (as opposed to the _blog_ link itself) then _(new)_ simply disappears - this is a little confusing at first, and might have people thinking 'meh, I can't be bothered, then' when it just goes away without redirecting them to the blog.

Comment: I think that an interface element isn't really the answer. I think we need to do something like start embedding blog posts in answers or comments (important - only **where appropriate**), or something else that's equally visible. When people see an interface element they don't understand, they tend to ignore it. And I think that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 2):

Each site's community can also promote their BlogOverflow blog by creating [community ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) that will be displayed on the sidebar of that site.

Comment: Note that only graduated sites have community ads.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize SO had a blog.... I think the issue is that most people (like me) don't usuall read the footer of a website. Maybe the blog link could be moved the the right hand side bar.

Comment: it's not in the footer, it is in the header.. on main sites that have a http://blogoverflow.com blog, and always on metas. See above screenshot.

Comment: @Jeff That indeed is hard to miss. Misunderstood, I thought that the text itself was red.

Comment: @Jeff The bicycles stackoverflow site has "review chat meta about faq". The answer above indicates that it only shows "blog" when there's a new post

Comment: @Mac, note that if you go to [the Bicycles Meta site](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/) the blog link is at the top.

Comment: @M. Tibbits - I clicked on the link you provided, but can't see a blog link at the top. It says "review chat main about faq"

Comment: Perhaps that's a 24 hour thing?  I see the chat link here too.